# Material TabLayout elevation not working

Tags: android, material-design, android-elevation

For some reason the elevation attribute does not seem to be working on the new TabLayout in the material design support library. Any ideas?
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="6dp" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

hooked up like this in a parent fragment:

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
AppPagerAdapter appPagerAdapter = new AppPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(appPagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

image:
[image: relevant image]

The activity has a toolbar but this is outside of the fragment and should not affect the tablayout's ability to have a shadow:

relevant activity xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.bluckapps.appinfomanager.ui.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using a `Toolbar` (I know it doesn't say in your layout but I'm just wondering)? Also note that the `android:elevation` attribute would only work with API levels 21 and higher (i.e. Android Lollipop (5.0) and higher).

Comment: the look should have the shadow below the tabs, rather than above them. the toolbar is in the activity outside of the fragment. I can expand the question a bit to elaborate

Comment: Have you tried:
_<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>_ in your style? This should remove the shadow under the ActionBar. Then you could add a View in your xml just on top of the layout that shows a darker color.

Comment: You may look this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179408

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To make the shadow show, you have to set a background on your TabLayout. It can be the same color as your window background (as long as it's a solid color with no alpha).

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```

Comment: careful, only v21+

Comment: This didn't work for me without adding a bottom margin. For an elevation of 4dp, ```android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"``` did the job.

Answer (score 7):

You are supposed to use `ToolBar` with `TabLayout`. Then you can put them both inside an `AppBarLayout` and get a shadow. This only works on Lollipop+.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

See http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en

Comment: this doesn't actually answer the question. does the elevation work on the tablayout by itself or not?

Comment: This is just a workaround and possibly the best practice for the issue. I don't know the exact reason as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: well thanks for that but is there a relevant bug or reason it isn't working? I guess what I'm asking is am I using it incorrectly or is there actually a google bug somewhere?

Comment: I'm pretty confident that this is the best practice for TabLayout. Wrapping it with AppBar. In future releases of design library, google may add shadow support to prte lollipop.

Comment: It's not about prelollipop the entire question is only about 5.0+. And that still doesn't answer what is actually going wrong

Comment: I think Binoy's solution is the best practice for this situation. Is there any reason why you need the `TabLayout` in the separate layout - it could just be part of the same layout wrapped in an `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: It would change the architecture of the app. If you nest it with the toolbar it makes it less modular and more difficult to support different screen sizes. Plus it's just one more level of view hierarchy.  In general it should be possible to use tablayout without toolbar correct?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use **CoordinatorLayout** as a container layout for your activity and then place your TabLayout right below AppBarLayout.
According to Material Design specs you should use

```
android:elevation="4dp"
```

elevation and make your TabLayout be a part of AppBarLayout.
Also note that elevation will only be visible on v21 (5.0) or higher.

Comment: You should probably use `app:elevation`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a `Fragment`. An Activity layout is enough. Like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/home_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:paddingStart="0dp">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_appcompat"></include>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
            style="@style/TabLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabContentStart="2dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabMinWidth="24dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabPadding="1dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:paddingEnd="0dp"
        app:paddingStart="0dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_toggle"
        app:borderWidth="1dp"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/home_coordinator_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="2dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/swipe_refresh_color_scheme_green" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Meanwhile, `elevation` is useful on Lollipop. If you want to be compatible backwards, you'd better use `app:elevation`. If `app:elevation` doesn't work, you'd better add a shadow below `TabLayout` manually, just like `android:background="@drawable/myrect"`:

```
<!-- res/drawable/myrect.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#42000000" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score -6):

All answers above didn't work for me ,so i found out this:

```
app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
```

then allright!